# SQL JSON Array, extract field from each element items into concatenated string

Tags: json, sql-server

I've got a JSON column containing an array of items:

```
[
  {
    "type": "banana"
  },
  {
    "type": "apple"
  },
  {
    "type": "orange"
  }
]
```

I want to select one column with a concatenated type, resulting in `'banana, apple, orange'`.

Thanks,
David

Comment: So what's stopping you? There's plenty of questions on how to consume JSON in SQL Server on [so], and even more questions on how to create delimited (comma) results in SQL Server. What about those didn't you understand? Why didn't your attempt(s) work? What *were* said attempts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse and aggregate the stored JSON:

```
SELECT 
   JsonColumn,
   NewColumn = (
      SELECT STRING_AGG(JSON_VALUE([value], '$.type'), ',') 
             WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CONVERT(int, [key]))
      FROM OPENJSON(t.JsonColumn)
   )   
FROM (VALUES
   ('[{"type":"banana"},{"type":"apple"},{"type":"orange"}]')
) t (JsonColumn)
```

Result:

| JsonColumn | NewColumn |
| --- | --- |
| [{"type":"banana"},{"type":"apple"},{"type":"orange"}] | banana,apple,orange |